# Tensorflow tf.data.Dataset convert string tensor to float tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to build a data input pipeline to read bounding box information.
Therefore I've got multiple `.txt` files which store information about `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` in each row, for example:

```
952  607    9   18
947 1176   14   12
937  228   17   22
895 1118   66   53
804  596   12   13
651  722   13    8
667  306   28   51
586 1148   20   32
231  280   33   31
859  629  102  172
806  486  155  111
487  506   55   69
263  476  372  339
4  589  114  106
273  724  164  192
4    4  350  292
```

All filenames are saved in a `list`

```
filenames_bb = input_tools.get_required_filenames(args.dataset_dir, "train", params)
```

I use `tf.data.Dataset` to build the input pipeline

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames_bb)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_fnc, params.num_parallel_calls)
```

Now my question is how to implement the `parse_fnc`? What I want is a tensor of shape `[batch_size, number_of_bounding_boxes, 4]`. Currently the `parse_fnc` looks as follows:

```
def parse_fnc(filenames):
    bb = tf.read_file(filenames)

    return bb
```

It returns a tensor of `shape=(?,)` and `dtype=string`, but how can I convert it to a `float` tensor with required dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataset containing the lines of one or more text files by calling `tf.TextLineDataset`. Then you can use `tf.string_split` and `tf.string_to_number` to obtain float values.

```
def parse_fnc(line):
    string_vals = tf.string_split([line]).values
    return tf.string_to_number(string_vals, tf.float32)

string_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset('./data.txt')
float_ds = string_ds.map(map_func=parse_fnc)
```

This example creates the dataset from one file, but you can provide multiple text files as input.